# Seed db with sequelize seed files before running tests with

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, jestjs

How do I do rake style commands in my test file (Jest) with sequelize seeder files?

I'm trying to do the same thing as this, but with sequelize.

```
describe('routes : movies', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    return knex.migrate.rollback()
    .then(() => { return knex.migrate.latest(); })
    .then(() => { return knex.seed.run(); });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    return knex.migrate.rollback();
  });


});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. The seeders are run through the Sequelize-CLI, not in application code. With that in mind, I don't think there's a function you could call (like your knex.seed method). FWIW, what I've done in the past is create JSON files that I import to bulk create test data.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to answer this but I just spent the past week trying to solve this issue. I have been able to successfully do this using Sequelize in conjunction with their sister project, Umzug. You will have to read the documentation for your specific issue but I can copy my test file so you can get an idea of how I did it. I'm happy to help someone if they still struggle with it after looking at the files.

```
// account.test.js
const models = require('../models/index.js');
const migrations = require("../index");

beforeAll(async () => {
    await migrations.up().then(function() {
        console.log("Migration and seeding completed")
    });
});

afterAll( async () => {
    await migrations.down().then(function() {
        console.log("Migrations and down seeding completed");
    })
    const users = await models.User.findAll();
    expect(users).toStrictEqual([]);
});

describe("Integration Test", () => {
    it("Account integration test", async () => {
        const data = { userId: 1210}
        const users = await models.User.findAll();
        console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(users, null, 2));
        expect(users[0].firstName).toBe('John');
        expect(data).toHaveProperty('userId');
    });
});
```

My index.js file

```
// index.js
const config = require('/config/config.json');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { Umzug, SequelizeStorage } = require('umzug');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);

const umzugMigration = new Umzug({
  migrations: { glob: 'migrations/*.js' },
  context: sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
  storage: new SequelizeStorage({ sequelize }),
  logger: console,
});

const umzugSeeding = new Umzug({
  migrations: { glob: 'seeders/*.js' },
  context: sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
  storage: new SequelizeStorage({ sequelize }),
  logger: console,
});


module.exports.up = () => umzugMigration.up().then(() => umzugSeeding.up());
module.exports.down = () => umzugSeeding.down();
```

Answer (score -5):

I think you **shouldn't make real** **DB** **requests** while testing your code. **Mock your DB request** and return the data set from your mock function if it's needed. Otherwise, it looks like you testing a library, in your case this lib is **knex**.

Read for more details regarding mocks https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions